# git vscode too many to show

Tags: git, npm, visual-studio-code

I get too many revisions in a single file project.
I think it was related to the npm install of angular without global but I don't know for sure.
I deleted the hidden git files in my home dir, thinking that it made my home directory a whole project,  but it didn't matter (I reset my config from home dir home/bhante)

I remember this showing up after the angular/cli install without -g
I bet that is it.. but how to fix?

2nd question is .. if I install angular and http server without -g will that matter?
I get so many difficulties installing with the global param.
kubuntu 20.04

[image: screenshot of vscode git message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository mentioned in the error message is `/home/bhante`, which is your home directory.

For some reason (willingly or unwillingly), I guess you ran `git init` in your home directory, and that your "Test Project", on the other hand, is not a git repository yet.

For your project :

- try running `git init` in the project directory, and see if the error still shows up.

For the git repo rooted at your home directory :

- if you didn't intend to version your home directory with git : just remove the `.git/` directory in `/home/bhante`
- if you did intend to version your home directory : you probably want to set a `.gitignore` there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem id due to node_modules..

Try adding a .gitignore, i.e create a file .gitignore add these lines.

.gitignore

```
/node_modules/
```

For more about this check [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gitignore-what-is-it-and-how-to-add-to-repo/) .

Comment: Why would they be included in a single file project.?  How to stop that.?